# How to solve the diophantine equation:$ xa^3+yb^3=c^3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}> 1$.  Any hint on how to solve of the diophantine equation $ xa^3+yb^3=c^3$?

Comment: The prime numbers tag doesn't seem right for this question, but I'm not very experienced with diophantine equations so I could be wrong. There is a diophantine equations tag which you might consider adding as well.

Comment: @JaycobColeman, thanks.

Comment: This is homework? Really? Even $a^3+b^3=c^3$ would be a difficult assignment. Unless the point is to pick $a,b,c$ first, making sure $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and then you just have to solve a linear diophantine equation for $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following relations:

$1^3+6^3+8^3=9^3$

$3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$

$⇒1^3+3^3+4^3+5^3+8^3=9^3$

or: $1^3 + 3^3+5^3+ 4^3(1+2^3)=9^3$

or: $(1^3 + 3^3+5^3). 1^3+ 4^3(1+2^3)=9^3$

or: $153 . 1^3 +4^3 . 9 = 9^3$

Compare this with equation:

$x a^3 + y b^3=c^3$

you find: $x=153, a=1, y=9, b=4, c=9$

It can be seen that there are infinitely many relations like $a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$. Now if two or more terms of LHS of relation, for example $b^3$ and $c^3$ have a common factor like k we have:

$b^3+c^3= k^3[(b/k)^3+(c/k)^3]$

That is relation $a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$ reduces to an equation like $X.A^3 +YB^3=C^3$ which indicates this equation may have many forms and solutions.

Comment: Num Thcurious please see my answer to your qestion